# How do I assign values to specific values for multiple children?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, variables, beautifulsoup

From my previous question, I asked how to parse multiple siblings from the same child, now I am curious how you take each output and have it equal to a unique variable. For example, I want Unkown out equal to Occupation and 656 equal to CarrierCode, and so on.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml='''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml='''
<AdditonalAttributes>
    <Attribute>
        <Name> Occupation </Name> 
        <Value> Unknown </Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <Name> CarrierCode </Name>
        <Value> 656 </Value>
    </Attribute>
<AdditonalAttributes>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

for a in soup.select('Attribute'):
    if a.Name.get_text(strip=True) in ['Occupation','CarrierCode']:
        print(a.Value.get_text(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
Unknown
656
```

Comment: So why do you want to assign each to a separat variable and what is your expected output?

Comment: Each xml file is a different user. So I need to parse a document for all the relevant information to then be able to put it into a database/csv file. The overall goal is to input the document via function and it will parse all the information into a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignment to variables is not clear but if you like to go the way along with `BeautifulSoup`to get a dict of your attributes:

```
dict(a.stripped_strings for a in soup.select('Attribute'))
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml='''
<AdditonalAttributes>
    <Attribute>
        <Name> Occupation </Name> 
        <Value> Unknown </Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <Name> CarrierCode </Name>
        <Value> 656 </Value>
    </Attribute>
<AdditonalAttributes>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

dict(a.stripped_strings for a in soup.select('Attribute'))
```

##### Output

```
{'Occupation': 'Unknown', 'CarrierCode': '656'}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I can't upvote but I would give this one an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to have a `dict` - see below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<AdditonalAttributes>
    <Attribute>
        <Name> Occupation </Name> 
        <Value> Unknown </Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <Name> CarrierCode </Name>
        <Value> 656 </Value>
    </Attribute>
</AdditonalAttributes>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = {a.find('Name').text: a.find('Value').text for a in root.findall('.//Attribute')}
print(data)
```

output

```
{' Occupation ': ' Unknown ', ' CarrierCode ': ' 656 '}
```

Comment: I can't use ElementTree as I get an issue with there being an extra space in the document.